# Numpy array scaling not returning proper values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that I want to alter by scaling all of the columns (e.g. all the values in a column are divided by the maximum value in that column so that all values are <1).

A sample output of the array is

[   2.       0.     367.877 ...,   -0.358   51.547  -32.633]

[   2.       0.     339.824 ...,   -0.33    52.562  -27.581]

[   3.       0.     371.438 ...,   -0.406   55.108  -35.573]

I've tried scaling the array (data_in) by the following code:

```
#normalize the data_in array 
data_in_normalized = data_in / data_in.max(axis=0)
```

However, the output of data_in_normalized is:

[ 0.5          0.           0.95437199   0.89363654   0.80751792 ]

[ 0.46931238   0.50660904   0.5003812    0.91250444   0.625 ]

[ 0.96229214   0.89483109   0.86989432   0.86491407   0.71287646 ]

[ -23.90909091   0.34346373   1.25110652   0.           0.8537859    1.           1.]

Clearly, it didn't normalize--there are multiple areas where the maximum value is >1. Is there a better way to scale the data, or am I using the max() function incorrectly (e.g. is the max() value being shared between columns?)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, it's not that the maximum value is shared between columns, it's that you probably want to divide by the maximum *absolute* value instead, because you have elements of both signs. 1 > -100, after all, and so if you divide by the *maximum* value of a column with [1, -100], nothing would change.

For example:

```
>>> data_in = np.array([[-3,-2],[2,1]])
>>> data_in
array([[-3, -2],
       [ 2,  1]])
>>> data_in.max(axis=0)
array([2, 1])
>>> data_in / data_in.max(axis=0)
array([[-1.5, -2. ],
       [ 1. ,  1. ]])
```

but

```
>>> data_in / np.abs(data_in).max(axis=0)
array([[-1.        , -1.        ],
       [ 0.66666667,  0.5       ]])
```